# Jest test on functions which are in onMounted Composition API Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-composition-api

Can anyone tell me how to write a test case for the functions which are in `onMounted` hook? I am using vue 2 with composition api plugin.

```
    const getUsers = async () => {
            const usersQuery = `
                query {
                  users: {
                     id
                     username
                   }
                }
            `
            try {
                const result = await apolloClient.getGraphqlData(usersQuery)
                if (result) users.value = result.data.users
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('Error while receiving users', err)
            }
        }
```

Below is my `onMounted` hook

```
onMounted(() => {
    getUsers()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mock local functions defined in `setup()`. The functions have to be exposed so that the unit tests can access them. One workaround is to declare the methods in an external file, adjacent to the component:

```js
// mylib.js
export const getUsers = async () => { /*...*/ }
```

And import that file in your component:

```js
import { onMounted } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { getUsers } from './mylib'

export default {
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => getUsers())
  }
}
```

Then in your test file, import the same file, and use `jest.mock()` to auto-mock it, which would allow you to verify that the function was called upon the component mounting:

```js
import { getUsers } from '@/components/mylib'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue'

jest.mock('@/components/setupFns')

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => jest.resetAllMocks())

  it('calls getUsers() on mount', () => {
    shallowMount(MyComponent)
    expect(getUsers).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

[demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue2-test-setup-methods)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you tell me how to do this when we have the function inside the component?

Comment: See the beginning of the answer. You can't test local methods inside setup because they're hidden.